# Allow deselecting a message by tapping them again

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

It's great that we can access more options by tapping on a message. But what about a tap-to-deselect? At the moment, we have to press the close button on the top left of the screen.

Advantages:

- Seems intuitive to me. I keep trying to do it!
- Easier for one-handed operation for right-handed people.

Disadvantages:

[image]

Comment: That makes sense and I'll probably add that. Has been suggested before though.